# Regular expression for a string to split the string into parts

Tags: java, regex

I have a string - `+3]##i recently purchased the canon powershot g3 and am extremely satisfied with the purchase . use`

I want to replace `+3]##` with `(blankspace/whitespace)`

**Output:**
`i recently purchased the canon powershot g3 and am extremely satisfied with the purchase . use`

There are multiple occurrence of `+3]##` and the number keeps changing some times it `+3]##` and sometimes it can be `+1##]` or `-1]##`

Can anyone help me with the regular expression to replace all such string to blank.

Thanks.

Comment: what is this , what you are trying to achieve? what is the string you want to split and what should be the output, what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have file with customer reviews. In that file the data is not in correct format.

Comment: And note: as written right now, you allow for either one plus sign or one digit. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You dont get it: if you want us to help you, post your code. If a newbie who hasnt a clue how to write down a regex; then chances are high that your code simply doesn't match the input values you want to process. We cant know if you dont give that information to use. So: update your question. Now!

Comment: It should be plus or minus sign the digit. Here both the sign and number are mandatory. Text can we in [+n]## or [-n]##.

Comment: Edited the question now it should be clear.

Comment: Not at all. You just dumped a **ton** of stuff at us. Read about a **minimal** complete example. Your question is as bad as it was before; you simply replaced "too little" with "too much" information. We are **not** here to dive through hundreds of lines of text! Post the code you have now, and give **short** examples of input and expected output.

Comment: I am unable beak the data as desired output as said in the post.

Comment: I have updated the question now. I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to match the contents inside `[ ]` also the followed text in form of either `(##|*)`

```
\[(.*?)\]|(##|\*)
```

`\[(.*?)\]` it will match the words `[t] [+3] [+2] [+2] [+1] [+2] [+2] [+1]` and `(##|\*)` will match the words `##* or ##`.

**Java code:**

```
String data="[+3]##i recently purchased the canon powershot g3 and am extremely satisfied with the purchase . use";
    String regex="\\[(.*?)\\]|(##|\\*)";
    System.out.println(data.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

**Output:**
`i recently purchased the canon powershot g3 and am extremely satisfied with the purchase . use`

It will work for your file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
^[+-][0-9]{1,}[\]#]{1,}
```

if you are using JAVA, then

```
"HERE YOUR STRING".replaceAll("^[+-][0-9]{1,}[\]#]{1,}", "");
```

if you are using bash/sh:

```
echo $your_string | sed 's/^[+-][0-9]\{1,\}[\\]#]{1,}//g'
```

If that doesn´t work for you, let´t me know. But would be nice to know in which language you are trying to do that.